# UIMA Ruta: Can't ignore periods using MarkTable

Tags: uima, ruta

If I have a dictionary containing various acronyms and designations, I would ideally like to be able to avoid having entries for each "U.S.A.", "USA", and "usa". I have no trouble ignoring case, but the ignore chars argument does not seem to work across the board. After the appropriate import and declare statements, I get something like the following:

Document{->MARKTABLE(Acroynm,1,AcronymDict,true,0,".,-",10,"expandedForm"=2)};

It successfully ignores a single set of 1-10 hyphens. It does not ignore 10 hyphens spaced throughout the word. (It will ignore a-bc and a--bc but not a-b-c.) This is actually fine for hyphens, but I cannot, with the above statement, get it to ignore periods at all. (It ignores neither a.bc or a.b.c.) Further, if I can get it to ignore periods, is there any way I can ignore the periods in A.B.C. and not just the one in A.BC?

Any further description of the limitations of this argument would be useful. Thanks.

Relevant Ruta Documentation: https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.language.actions.marktable

Comment: I assume that annotations of type Acronym are created but the feature is not assigned? Else, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Given your rule and a table like "abc;feature", annotations are created for any variations like "a.b.c". However, the "feature" is not assigned to the feature of the annotation. This will be fixed in the next release. Can you narrow down your problem? Maybe the table contains some entries with equal prefixes if the ignored chars are removed?

Comment: I fixed the problems that I could observe in the current trunk. MarkTableTest.java tests the functionality.

Comment: That seems to be the case. I was unable to reproduce my issue with a minimal wordtable containing only "abc." I will look at the dictionary I'm using. Thank you so much for the timely response! (And also Ruta.)

Comment: You are welcome. We had similar problems, especially when the dictionary contains different variants with whitespaces and without. I normally suggest to remove all chars from the dictionary that are skipped later when it is applied. So, no punctation marks or spaces in the entries.